# PHP Generated JS photo slider?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm wondering if anyone can help. I can't spot why it's not working. I'm not amazing with JS but the logic is there in my head. I'm simply after pulling the image contents of a specified folder (or a default one should none be specified in the URL) and having them sequentially displayed in an img.

```
<img src="./img/samples/sample1.jpg"  class="gallery_image" name="slideshow_image">

<?php

if($_GET["med"])
{
    $files = glob('./img/samples/' . $_GET["med"] . '/*.{jpg}', GLOB_BRACE);
}
else
{
    $files = glob('./img/samples/*.{jpg}', GLOB_BRACE);
}
echo    '<script type="text/javascript">';
$n = 1;
foreach($files as $file)
{
    echo    'var image' . $n . ' = new Image();'
        ,   'image' . $n . '.src = "' . $file . '";';
    $n++;
}
echo    'var step = 1;'
    ,   'function slideit()'
    ,   '{'
    ,   '   document.images.slideshow_image.src = eval("image"+step+".src");'
    ,   '   if(step < ' . $n . ')'
    ,   '       step++;'
    ,   '   else'
    ,   '       step = 1;'
    ,   '   setTimeout("slideit()",2500);'
    ,   '}'
    ,   'slideit();';
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this is a problem with PHP or Javascript? It would be useful to see the rendered HTML...

Comment: its real code ? I don't believe....

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing in HTML, PHP and JavaScript the worst possible way.

Of course you can make this work, but it will cost you a lot of efforts, and trying to make it evolve will be a cruel pain.

You should define a clear interface each 3 languages, instead of half-generating JavaScript code within a PHP script intertwined with HTML code.

What PHP must do is find the list of images to be displayed.
The job of JavaScript is to animate the slideshow.
HTML is there to present the images.

Here is a possible solution:

```
<?php
// returns a javascript array initializer
function slideshow_files ($dir)
{
    $dir = $dir ? "/".$dir : "";
    $files = glob('./img/samples' . $dir . '/*.{jpg}', GLOB_BRACE);
    return "[".implode (',', $files)."]";
}
?>
<head>
<script>
// an anonymous function to avoid polluting global context
(function () {

    // get your image list from PHP
    var imgs = <?= slideshow_files ($_GET["med"]); ?>;

    // preload images
    var image = [];
    for (var i = 0 ; i != slide_image.length ; i++)
    {
        image[i] = new Image;
        image[i].src = img[i];
    }

    // launch your slideshow
    var step = 0;
    slide();

    // slideshow timer proc
    function slide()
    {
       document.images.slideshow_image.src = image[step].src;
       step = (step+1) % image.length;
       setTimeout(slide, 2500);
    }
})();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="./img/samples/sample1.jpg"  class="gallery_image" name="slideshow_image">
</body>
```

Needless to say, you won't be able to write anything moderately complex if you keep dumping all your code into a big HTML file.